# How to make the row coloring work in Splunk JS?

Tags: javascript, css, splunk

My Splunk table contains four columns "Id", "Name", "Org", "Salary".

I want to mark all cells with bold font and some icons based on their values in "Salary". This part is working.

Additionally, I also want to color (or highlight) those rows entirely which has a specific icon ("alert") in the corresponding cell of the "Salary" column. This part is not working.

My JS code is below :

```
require([
    'underscore',
    'jquery',
    'splunkjs/mvc',
    'splunkjs/mvc/tableview',
    'splunkjs/mvc/simplexml/ready!'
], function(_, $, mvc, TableView) {
     // Row Coloring Example with custom, client-side range interpretation
    var CustomRangeRenderer = TableView.BaseCellRenderer.extend({
        canRender: function(cell) {
            // Enable this custom cell renderer for both the Age and the State field
            return _(['Id', 'Name', 'Org', 'Salary']).contains(cell.field);

        },
        render: function($td, cell) {
            // Add a class to the cell based on the returned value
            var value = cell.value;
            // Apply interpretation for number of historical searches
            if (cell.field === 'Salary') {
                if (value > 2) {
                 $td.addClass('range-cell').addClass('range-elevated');
                
                }
            var icon;

            if(value > 200) {

                icon = 'alert';
            } else if (value > 100) {
                icon = 'alert-circle';
            }
            else {

                icon = 'check';
               
            }
   
            // Create the icon element and add it to the table cell

            $td.addClass('icon-inline numeric').html(_.template('<%- text %> <i class="icon-<%-icon%>"></i>', {

                icon: icon,

                text: cell.value

            }));

        }
    });

    mvc.Components.get('table1').getVisualization(function(tableView) {
        // Add custom cell renderer
        tableView.table.addCellRenderer(new CustomRangeRenderer());
        tableView.on('rendered', function() {
            // Apply class of the cells to the parent row in order to color the whole row
            tableView.$el.find('td.range-cell').each(function() {
                $(this).parents('tr').addClass(this.className);
            });
        });
        // Force the table to re-render
        tableView.table.render(); 
    });  

});
```

And my css is below :

```
/* Custom Icons */
td.icon {
    text-align: center;
}
td.icon i {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #aaa;
}
td.icon .severe {
    color: red;
}
td.icon .elevated {
    color: orangered;
}
td.icon .low {
    color: #006400;
}

.icon-inline i {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.icon-inline i.icon-alert-circle {
    color: #ef392c;
}
.icon-inline i.icon-alert {
    color: #ff9c1a;
}
.icon-inline i.icon-check {
    color: #5fff5e;
}
/* Dark Theme */
td.icon i.dark {
    text-shadow: none;
}
/* Row Coloring */

 #table1 tr td {
     background-color: #c1ffc3 !important;
 }
 #table1 tr.range-elevated td {
     background-color: #ffc57a !important;
 }
 #table1 tr.range-severe td {
     background-color: #d59392 !important;
 }
 #table1 .table td {
     border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 }
 #table1 td.range-severe, td.range-elevated {
     font-weight: bold;
 }
```

What changes do I need to make to paint all rows having icon as "alert" to green (or any specific color) ?

Thanks